# What haphened if i connect Azure Active Directory with Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory

we have Azure Devops and  Azure Active Directory, they are not connected with each other. In our Azure Devops we have a lot of users with external emails also users with organization email: What happened with users, who have external emails?

And second question, can be the connection process be reverted?

Thanks in advance.

not tried at all)
no idea what happened with external users

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer can give you some help

Comment: Trying to dedicate the connection day, it must be non working day

Comment: Will wait for your feedback.

Comment: Any updates? Feel free to let me know if you need any further assistance

Answer (score 0):

> What happened with users, who have external emails?

After connecting to the AAD with Azure DevOps, the users with the organization email can directly access the organization.

The users with external emails will have no access to Organization.

To let the users with external emails to access to organization, we need to add the external emails to AAD as Guest. Or we need to map the users with External email to the AAD user account.

For more detailed info and steps. You can refer to this doc: [Connect your organization to Microsoft Entra ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/connect-organization-to-azure-ad?view=azure-devops#connect-your-organization-to-microsoft-entra-id-1)

> And second question, can be the connection process be reverted?

Yes. We can reverted the connection process. We can disconnect AAD with the **Disconnect directory** option.

For more detailed steps， refer to this doc: [Disconnect organization from directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/disconnect-organization-from-azure-ad?view=azure-devops#disconnect-organization-from-directory)